# Where did the term "superuser" originate?

Tags: sudo, root, terminology, su

Where did the term "superuser" originate? Is it a shortening of "supervisory user", or is it just an indicator of the level of power one such user holds in a system?

Comment: I am curious why superuser.com is named superuser. Is it the same connection? Does it come from Unix and the super-user from that operating system?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### Where did the term "superuser" originate?

> su allows one to become the super--user, who has all sorts
>                     of marvelous powers.

From the [First Edition Unix](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V1) su man page:

```
        11/3/71                                                        SU (I)


NAME              su -- become privileged user

SYNOPSIS          su password

DESCRIPTION       su allows one to become the super--user, who has all sorts
                  of marvelous powers. In order for su to do its magic, the
                  user must pass as an argument a password. If the password
                  is correct, su will execute the shell with the UID set to
                  that of the super--user. To restore normal UID privileges,
                  type an end--of--file to the super--user shell

FILES

SEE ALSO          shell

DIAGNOSTICS       "Sorry" if password is wrong

BUGS

OWNER             dmr, ken
```

Source [minnie.tuhs.org/UnixTree/V5/usr/source/s2/su.c.html](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V1/man/man1/su.1)

`su` is used on Unix systems to change user, and is commonly used to run commands as the root user.

And ... read on

> I had another foundation shaking moment with the meaning of "su". I
>   found some old Unix source code, [where su.c was available](http://minnie.tuhs.org/UnixTree/V5/usr/source/s2/su.c.html).
>   Curious, I looked at the source. What did I find?
>
> ```
> /* su -- become super-user */
>
> char    password[100];
> char    pwbuf[100];
> int ttybuf[3];
> main()
> {
>     register char *p, *q;
>     extern fin;
>
>     if(getpw(0, pwbuf))
>         goto badpw;
>     (&fin)[1] = 0;
>     p = pwbuf;
>     while(*p != ':')
>         if(*p++ == '\0')
>             goto badpw;
>     if(*++p == ':')
>         goto ok;
>     gtty(0, ttybuf);
>     ttybuf[2] =& ~010;
>     stty(0, ttybuf);
>     printf("password: ");
>     q = password;
>     while((*q = getchar()) != '\n')
>         if(*q++ == '\0')
>             return;
>     *q = '\0';
>     ttybuf[2] =| 010;
>     stty(0, ttybuf);
>     printf("\n");
>     q = crypt(password);
>     while(*q++ == *p++);
>     if(*--q == '\0' && *--p == ':')
>         goto ok;
>     goto error;
>
> badpw:
>     printf("bad password file\n");
> ok:
>     setuid(0);
>     execl("/bin/sh", "-", 0);
>     printf("cannot execute shell\n");
> error:
>     printf("sorry\n");
> }
> ```
>
> What is the first comment in that C file?
>
> ```
> /* su -- become super-user */
> ```
>
> `su` was written to only change to the root user on the system. It
>   wasn't designed to switch to any other user that has an account. "su"
>   meant "super-user". I need to sit down for a second.
>
> The code above comes from the fifth edition of Unix by Dennis Ritchie
>   and Ken Thompson. If you know your Unix history, it really wasn't
>   until the sixth edition that things really started taking off for the
>   Unix world. So, it's safe to say that most, if not all, of the code in
>   the fifth edition and prior were written by Dennis and Ken themselves.
>   Fifth edition Unix released in 1975, so it doesn't get much more
>   authoritative than that.

Source [Aaron Toponce : The Meaning of 'su'](https://pthree.org/2009/12/31/the-meaning-of-su/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [history - Origin of 'root' account - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7960/origin-of-root-account)
- [Superuser - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser)
- [sudo - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72047/discussion-on-answer-by-davidpostill-where-did-the-term-superuser-originate).

Answer (score 35):

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/308570) (paywalled) gives the following etymology:

> super- *prefix* + user *n.*

The earliest example that they list is from K. Thompson & D. M. Ritchie (1971): "Unix Programmer's Man.":

> Only the super-user may invoke this command.